# jQuery and getting scroll position only on every 200 scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the scroll down and up position at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hvg019xw/1/)  but as you can see it is updating the `<p>` element on every single pixel by pixel scroll (Up or Down). But what I need to only update the `<p>` on every 200 scroll until reaching the end of the div (right now the p element is updating on every single scroll).

Here is the code I have:

```js
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();
    if (height > 200) {
        $('p').html(height);
    }
});
```

```css
div {
    height:1080px;
}
p {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
<div>
    <h3> Hello Scroll!</h3>
</div>
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var a=0;
$(window).scroll(function () {
    var height = $(window).scrollTop();
    
    if (height-a<200){
        if (height-a<-200){
            $('p').html(a);
            a = parseInt(height/100) *100;
        }
    }else{
        $('p').html(a);
        a = parseInt(height/100)*100;
    }  
});
```

```css
div {
    height:1080px;
}
p {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p></p>
<div>
    <h3> Hello Scroll!</h3>
</div>
```